# Order of array items after serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I want to build a logic depending on the array items sequence after serialization. 
So i need to confirm whether the sequence of array items which i have sent from client side as JSON remains same?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be better to add some part of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It absolutely does remain the same. A serializer which reordered the elements of an array would be broken.

A basic requirement of a serializer is:

```
Contract.Assume(Deserialize(Serialize(object)).Equals(object));
```

Comment: I was sure about this, just wanted to confirm.